# PHP file upload with iframe - announce start and end of upload

Tags: php, iframe, file-upload

so I have a PHP iframe (ajax) file uploader. I would like to display a loading message when submit is clicked (easy on click event) and then once the file is uploaded, so when the iframe is loaded with the PHP response, vanish (jquery fadeOut) and an alert box pop up saying the file is uploaded. what would be the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: Look at [Valums file uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/).

Comment: I dnt want to use a plugin, Security is too much of a risk with plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach an event handler to [*load*](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) on the iframe and put your fade out logic in there.

**Edit 2:** Some sample code (changed from ready to load)

```
<iframe name="process"></iframe>

<form method="post" action="upload.php" target="process" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="Upload.start()">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

<script>
    var Upload = function() {

        $(function() {
            $('iframe[name=process]').load(function() {
            // finished uploading file
                $('.loading-div').hide('slow', function() {
                    alert('Your file has been successfully uploaded.');
                });
            });
        });

        return {
            start: function() {
                $('.loading-div').show();
            }
        }
    }();  
</script>
```

Comment: $('iframe[name=process]').ready(function()

Runs before the file has finished uploading, also I would like to give a response based on the PHP processing of the file, Which get dumped in the frame sadly

Comment: Working, Awsum, tnks soooo much